# Using regular expression text box should accept 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 Max digits numbers only restrict decimal part

Tags: asp.net

I need to validate the text box at server side by using regular exp which should accept 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 digits numbers .Need to restrict decimal part.

Ex: 1 or 23 or 455 or 5643 or 45667 --Should accept.

1.3, .2, 33.3 , 444.55 ,5555.99 -- should not accept.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

^[0]$|^[1-9][\d]{0,4}$

OR

^[0]$|^[1-9][0-9]{0,4}$

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use two [CompareValidators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw.aspx). One to validate if the user has entered an integer an one that validates if the value is less than 100000.

To make a CompareValidator check for integers, set  `Operator="DataTypeCheck"` and `Type="Integer"`. To check if it is less than  100000 set `Operator="LessThan"` and `ValueToCompare="100000"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like `@"^\d{1,5}$"`